# Yii Unset Session

Tags: php, session, yii

I have a `Session variable` in yii which corresponds to the particular user state

```
Yii::app()->user->setState('mycustomvar', 550);
```

So that I could get this variable as

```
Yii::app()->user->mycustomvar
```

How can I `unset` only this variable?

I got a solution Like this

```
Yii::app()->session->remove(Yii::app()->user->getStateKeyPrefix() . 'mycustomvar');
```

Is this a right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ran into a solution by using this

```
Yii::app()->session->remove(Yii::app()->user->getStateKeyPrefix() . 'mycustomvar');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Yii::app()->user->setState('mycustomvar', null);
```

Or whatever other initial /default value you've used while setting the variable.

See [the docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#setState-detail). Whenever you set the variable to default value (`null` unless explicitly set to other value), it will be removed from the session.

EDIT:

Btw, you can also set it the same way via magic method, that is:

```
Yii::app()->user->mycustomvar = 550;
```

Comment: Not able to set the value like this Yii::app()->user->mycustomvar = 550;

Comment: @LifeHacker, sorry, I wasn't too clear about that. You can set properties like this once they have been set. So initial setting always has to be performed with `setState`. But then, you can, for instance, unset the property like this: `Yii::app()->user->mycustomvar = null` or set it to another value the same way.

Comment: Yii::app()->session->remove(Yii::app()->user->getStateKeyPrefix() . 'mycustomvar'); I got it removed Like this but is this Right way

Comment: Setting the state to null does exactly the same thing